# Require.js optimizer via msbuild doesn't work, but directly on command line does

Tags: node.js, msbuild, requirejs

in my code, the following command, executed on a powershell prompt

```
r.js -o name=main out=main_opt.js baseUrl=.
```

works fine and outputs the following

```
Tracing dependencies for: main
Uglifying file: C:/Users/Scott/Documents/d/proj/Scripts/Coffee/Directory/main_opt.js

C:/Users/Scott/Documents/d/proj/Scripts/Coffee/Directory/main_opt.js
----------------
C:/Users/Scott/Documents/d/proj/Scripts/Coffee/Directory/DirectoryVM.js
C:/Users/Scott/Documents/d/proj/Scripts/Coffee/Directory/main.js
```

via msbuild I get the following

```
RequireJSOptimize:
  working dir = C:\Users\Scott\Documents\d\proj\Scripts\Coffee\Directory\
  r.js -o name=main out=main_opt.js baseUrl=.

  node.js:203
          throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
                ^
  Error: Error evaluating module "undefined" at location "undefined":
  TypeError: Cannot call method 'write' of null
  fileName:undefined
  lineNumber: undefined
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#defineerror
      at makeError (C:\Users\Scott\Documents\d\GitHub\node\lib\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:179:17)
      at execManager 
....
  (C:\Users\Scott\Documents\d\GitHub\node\lib\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:598:17)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try a /v:diag on the msbuild command line.

Comment: I dunno. Diag is the first thing I do when troubleshooting msbuild errors. Usually it will contain some sort of clue. I'd also try it from the 'cmd' interpreter too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug with v 0.5.9 of node. Since fixed.